# Static Variable Turns Nil When Running Tests

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

We have a static variable with a default value:

`static NSDictionary *g_primaryKeyFieldName = NULL;`

That we initialize it with a proper value in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

`g_primaryKeyFieldName = [NSDictionary dictionary...];`

Everything seems to be fine when running the app normally. However, when running the tests, the variable gets initialized but then somehow its value is set to the initial `NULL` value again.

I checked the variable is not being just set to `nil` or deallocated because if I set its default value to be something else:

`static NSDictionary *g_primaryKeyFieldName = @"Some String";`

Then that's the value the variable gets.

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Do you see this behavior on every test? You say the variable gets initialized when running the tests – are you sure, and how do you know? Is this variable `static` within or without a function?

Comment: @RileyAvron I know because if I set a breakpoint in the initializing method, it gets called and I can see the variable properly initialized. The variable is static outside the function.

Comment: If it's static outside any function (i.e., a static global variable), then that variable's scope is limited to its translation unit. How are you getting the pointer "out" into the tests?

Comment: That pointer lives within a class (`FCModel` actually). I call its initialization method in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then I try to use it (`FCModel`) in my tests.

Comment: Are you sure that the instance of `FCModel` that you initialize in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is the same instance you're testing?

Comment: The static variable gets initialized in a class method. It seems like there were different processes for `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and the tests.

Comment: That sounds like your issue. And that would explain why setting the variable to a string worked.

Comment: It didn't seem like two processes were spawned by watching Activity Monitor. I've also looked at other static variables within `FCModel` and only this particular one is `nil`.

Comment: Be sure: check the memory address of the instance of `FCModel` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and compare it with the address of the `FCModel` in your tests.

Comment: FCModel doesn't have a mem address itself. It's a class from which all my DB entities inherit from. It has class methods and variables for actions and common state. Thanks for your help BTW!

Comment: No problem. I don't want to continue this sort of back-and-forth in the comments. Maybe we could take this into chat at some point if you're still banging your head against later.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem just happened to me and I found a possible reason. If a file (`FCModel.m`) is included in both application and test targets, separate contexts (static variables etc.) are created for calls from the application and from the tests. So the solution is: Make sure the `FCModel.m` file has target membership only in `MyFCApp` and if you need to access your `FCModel` class in tests, access it only via `@testable import MyFCApp`.

Answer (score -2):

```
static NSDictionary* g_primaryKeyFieldName = nil;

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    g_primaryKeyFieldName = @{
      @"k": @100,
      @"u": @400,
      @"m": @40,
      };
});
```

Comment: it may be helps you to save data in NSDictionary

Comment: An explanation of why your answer solves the problem wouldn't harm. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)